# What are the signs that you have been blacklisted by a company?

Tags: hiring-process

I always have this worry that a employer may have blacklisted me from an interview that did not work out too well. What signs would I notice if I have been blacklisted by a company?

Comment: Hi DrinkJavaCodeJava, is there any way you could add some more details to this question? As it stands, it's really coming off like a polling/list question instead of one about a real, actual problem you're facing. Consider adding details about your interview and what leads you to believe there's a blacklist. There seems like an awful lot of speculation here as it stands. Hope this helps! :)

Comment: I don't know about blacklisting *within* companies, but, you can learn about blacklisting by following the recent UK construction industry blacklisting scandal. [Here's a good introductory article](http://www.heraldscotland.com/news/home-news/companies-operated-a-blacklist-of-union-activists-they-took-peoples-livelihoods-away-they-should-be-jailed.192629). There's an inquiry and investigation going on, and it's turning up lots of interesting, sometimes shocking information. I don't know if any of it would be informative to your case though - it's much simpler to blacklist *within* one company.

Comment: The important thing to note about that case is, it's a genuine illegal clandestine endeavour to keep out "troublemakers" and weaken organisations like unions. If your fears are based on nothing more than an embarrassing interview, people just don't go to the same amount of trouble over such things. Maybe, if it was really bad, someone told the story of "this one guy in an interview one time", but it's unlikely they'd remember or tell the name. But people (sometimes the same people) do sometimes re-interview and employ people they'd interviewed before for different roles.

Answer (score 4):

First, it is unlikely that a company of any size would bother to maintain a blacklist (other than people that had been previously employed by the company that didn't work out).  An individual manager or group might recall that a particular candidate did poorly in a prior interview and decline to interview that person for a new position but that isn't particularly common given both the turnover in organizations, the number of groups that would have open positions, and the interviewer's tendency to forget all but the most awful interviews.

If you were, by chance, blacklisted, there wouldn't be any signs.  You simply wouldn't be called for an interview.  But since the vast majority of applicants for any particular position aren't called for an interview, you would never realistically know if you weren't called because of some deficiency in your resume or because of some blacklist.